# How do I check whether username stored as a ForeignKey field and request.user.username are equal in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am making a personal diary app in Django. Over there I have made an app 'note'. The models.py of note app looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Note(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    title=models.CharField(default="",max_length=20)
    body=models.TextField(default="",max_length=800)
    date=models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    publisher=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now when a user logs in, in his home page I want to show the note entries made by him only. The views.py and home.html are given below:

views.py:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    notes=Note.objects    
    return render(request,'home.html',{'notes':notes})
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% if error %}
{{error}}
{% endif %}
   {% for n in notes.all  %}
   {% ifequal request.user.username n.publisher  %}
   <div class="container">
   <a href="{% url 'note_app:detail' n.id %}"><h3>{{n.title}}</h3></a>
   <p>{{n.body}}</p>
   <footer>{{n.date}}</footer>
   </div>
   {% endifequal %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see in my home.html I am iterating through all the objects of class Note. When the `ifequal` statement is not there it is showing all the entries of all users but when I am putting the `ifequal` statement to make sure that entries made by the logged in user is only shown it is not showing anything. Can somebody tell me how to fix this? I'm an absolute beginner here in web development and I appologise in advance for a stupid question but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing the second parameter to `{% ifequal %}`. Right now, you're not comparing anything to anything. Try this:

**home.html:**

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% if error %}
{{error}}
{% endif %}
   {% for n in notes.all  %}
   {% ifequal request.user n.publisher %}
   <div class="container">
   <a href="{% url 'note_app:detail' n.id %}"><h3>{{n.title}}</h3></a>
   <p>{{n.body}}</p>
   <footer>{{n.date}}</footer>
   </div>
   {% endifequal %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

That said, I should note that you don't have to do this in your template. It'll be faster if you do it in the database. You can change your `views.py` to this:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    notes = Note.objects.filter(publisher=request.user)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'notes':notes})
```

at which point you won't even need the `{% ifequal %}` tag in the template.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mistake it's in views.py
try to use:

```
notes=Note.objects.all()
```

instead of:

```
notes=Note.objects
```

Comment: He's calling `all` in the template, however. It's a little nonstandard, but it does work to say `notes=notes.objects` in `views.py`, and then use `notes.all` in the template.